# What software is this?

Tags: pdf, preview, video-conference

After the start of the pandemic people have been using increasingly nicer software when giving talks on Zoom.  Among the nicest ones I've seen is one in which a PDF file is presented while the speaker scribbles on top of it or highlights parts of the text, the highlighting slowly disappearing as the speaker moves further down the page.  My question is simply which software is this, as I'd love to start using it myself.  Besides my short description above I can provide a screenshot of the menu bar in case anybody can help me name it!  [image]

Comment: Are you sure this is software running on macOS?

Comment: In fact I'm not, but the icons style suggests it is.

Comment: It lacks the usual close/minimize/expand buttons at top right. Could it be an iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is [GoodNotes 5](https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/goodnotes-5/id1444383602)

It is an universal app (iPhone, iPad & Mac)